# Different mysql connecion problems

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

my foreach get some error.
The error is following :

`bool(false) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /storage/content/34/123134`

I have bool(false) because I var_dump the variable. My code looks like this:

```
$getTheOffers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items_offer` , $connen");
foreach ($getTheOffers as $getTheOffer ) { ?>
```

$connen is the mysql_connection variable. and my select db looks like:

```
mysql_select_db($databaseInfo['sqldatabase'],$connen);
```

What is wrong here? Thanks for any support!

HERE IS COMPLETE foreach and mysql

```
    $getTheOffers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_offer", $connen);
if( is_array($getTheOffers) ) 
{
 foreach ($getTheOffers as $getTheOffer ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php if ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "plank") { ?>
                <img src="images/plank.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Plank) 
                <?php } elseif ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "panel") { ?>
                <img src="images/doubleplank.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Panel) 
                <?php } elseif ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "tape") { ?>
                <img src="images/tape.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Tape) 
                <?php } elseif ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "bolt") { ?>
                <img src="images/bolt.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Bolt) 
                <?php } elseif ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "nail") { ?>
                <img src="images/nail.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Nail)  
                <?php } elseif ($getTheOffer['offer_name'] == "screw") { ?>
                <img src="images/screw.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"> (Screw) 
                <?php }  ?> 
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $getTheOffer['offer_amount'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $getTheOffer['offer_need'];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } } else echo "Not work!";  ?>
```

Comment: Your code example isn't complete, the foreach call you show doesn't have a closing `}` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the missing code that I pointed out in a comment, your mysql_query call appears to be incorrect.

try this:

```
$getTheOffers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_offer", $connen);
```

Also try this to see what is going on with your query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_offer", $connen);
$getTheOffers = mysql_fetch_array($result)
if( is_array($getTheOffers) )
{    
    foreach ($getTheOffers as $getTheOffer ) {
        //... rest of your code goes here
    }        
} else{
    // output error information
}
```

Please refer [**`mysql_query`**](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) and [**`mysql_fetch_array`**](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) on official documentation site for more information.

Comment: I tried this, i still get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I've modified my answer to help you deduce what is going on with your query.

Comment: I get Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and also Notice: Undefined variable: getTheOffer

Comment: The query being returned may not be an array then.  I just modified my code again for you, please try again.

Comment: Basically I updated this to verify that you aren't getting an array back by making the `mysql_query` call.  If that is in fact true, you'll have to make the `msyql_fetch_array()` call like vishnu pointed out.

Comment: The errors dissapear, but i get the "Not work" message now. Look my main post, i posted whole things.

Comment: Try the mysql_fetch_array call that I've updated my answer with.  It's what Vishnu was getting at in his response.

Comment: Tried that, http://3.ii.gl/63Ihq_.png check that picture, that is how the table looks like

Answer (score 1):

I think you will still need to use

```
mysql_fetch_array()
```

then used it like this

```
$getTheOffers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_offer", $connen);

$getArray = mysql_fetch_array($getTheOffers);

foreach ($getArray as row)
{
    //do your code here
}
```

instead of directly using $getTheOffers on foreach

Note as well how the quoation marks are used as said on other comments in this question.

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed example? I didnt understand right.. Still noob at php lol

Comment: Basically what he's getting at is that the resource returned by mysql_query isn't an array, it's a resource.  So to get a list of items, you have to use the `mysql_fetch_array()` call.  Once you do that and it returns an array, then you can loop over the array with your foreach call.

Comment: Edited my answer. @Cornex try it

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**:
First of all, your `mysql_query` syntax is wrong - double quotes must be after the query
So, when you fire query, `$getTheOffers` get boolean `false` value.
Then you try to foreach it which will obviously give you warning thatyou have mentioned in question.

**In short**,
Your all problems mentioned in question will be resolved when you will write correct syntax for `mysql_query`:

```
$getTheOffers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items_offer", $connen);
```